# how to split four columns into two tables in sas report

Tags: sas, report

I have one table having 4 columns and i want to separate them into 2 table 2 columns in one table and 2 columns in another table.but both table should be below to each other.I want this in proc report format.code should be in report.

```
id name age gender
1  abc  21  m
2  pqr  23  f
3  qwe  25  f
4  ert  54  m
```

i want id and name in one table and age and gender in other table.but one below the other in ods excel.

Answer (score 0):

I've split the main table into two tables using a data setp then appended them to each other, I added an extra columns called "source" in order to be differniate between the tables. if you use a Proc report you can group by "source"

Code:

```
*Create input data*/
data have;
input id name $ age gender $  ;
datalines;
1 abc 21 m
2 pqr 23 f
3 qwe 25 f
4 ert 54 m
;;;;
run;
/*Split / create first table*/
data table1;
set have;
source="table1: id & name";
keep source id name ;
run;
/*Split / create second table*/
data table2;
set have;
source="table2: age & gender";
keep source age gender;
run;
/*create Empty table*/
data want;
length Source $30. column1 8. column2 $10.;
run;
proc sql; delete * from want; quit;
/* Append both tables to each other*/
proc append base= want data=table1(rename=(id=column1 name=column2)) force ; run;
proc append base= want data=table2(rename=(age=column1 gender=column2)) force ; run;
/*Create Report*/
proc report data= want;
col source column1 column2 ;
define source / group;
run;
```

Output Table:

[image: OutputTable]

Report:

[image: Proc Report]

Comment: solution is good but too lengthy process.i want this in single report procedure

Comment: @SushantShinde The desired output layout does not align with the original data.  Sometimes you just have to reshape the data in order to use the tool (REPORT).  There is no simple REPORT syntax to created the layout you want.  Pretty much any approach you take will have to split your big rectangle into little rectangles.

Comment: @Richard i used page but in excel the second table goes in another sheet. Thats not i want .the second table should below the first table

Comment: You need to use ODS EXCEL option `options(sheet_interval='NONE')`.  See my answer with sample out.

Answer (score 0):

For data

```
data have;input
id name $ age gender $; datalines;
1  abc  21  m
2  pqr  23  f
3  qwe  25  f
4  ert  54  m
run;
```

Being output as Excel, the splitting into two parts can be done via two `Proc REPORT` steps; each step responsible for a single set of columns.  Options are used in the `ODS EXCEL` to control how sheet processing is handled.

The first step manages the common header through `DEFINE`, the subsequent steps are `NOHEADER` and don't need `DEFINE` statements.  Each step must define and compute the value of the new `source` column.  There will be a one Excel row gap between each table.

```
ods _all_ close;
ods excel file='want.xlsx' options(sheet_interval='NONE');

proc report data=have;
  column source id name;
  define id / 'Column 1';
  define name / 'Column 2';
  define source / format=$20.;
  compute source / character length=20; source='ID and NAME'; endcomp;
run;
proc report data=have noheader;
  column source age gender;
  define source / format=$20.;
  compute source / character length=20; source='AGE and GENDER'; endcomp;
run;

ods excel close;
```

There is no reasonable **single** `Proc REPORT` step that would produce similar output from dataset `have`.

[image]